# Subscribed calendars on Windows 10 Mail app?

Tags: calendar, windows-10, webcal

The Windows 10 mail app also displays your calendar if youre configured for an Exchange server. Any idea if it's possible to add a subscribed calendar -- i.e. a shared calendar sent with a link like `webcal://...`? I sure don't find anything obvious in the "New Accounts" options or via internet search

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been able to get an ical/webcal in after a few attempts:

All you need to do is add your calendars to your live mail account.
Then remove and readd the account from your Windows 10 Calendar, and you will see them in there.

So it is not a direct method, but it works :)

Answer (score 7):

> - Go to http://calendar.live.com and log into your account
> - Click “Import” on the top bar then click “Subscribe” on the left
> - Paste your iCal feed into “Calendar URL”
> - Click “Subscribe” to add the feed

Source: http://dottech.org/190699/how-to-add-ical-feed-to-windows-10-calendar-app-tip/

Comment: Damn, here I was telling myself in the middle of my work flow that it would only take a couple of seconds to add a calendar before getting back to what I was doing.

Comment: These instructions don't work for the current version of the Outlook.com website.

Comment: I believe the options have changed a bit. Now it is `Add Calendar` on left side bar and then click on `Subscribe from web`

Answer (score 5):

Instructions updated for March 2020:

First, subscribe to the calendar at Outlook.com:

1. Go to https://outlook.live.com/calendar/ and log in
2. Click Add calendar on the left sidebar
3. Click Subscribe from web on the left sidebar of the dialog that appears
4. Paste in your iCal URL, add a calendar name if you want, and click Import

[image: Screenshot of dialog of adding a calendar]

Then, if you haven't already add your Outlook.com account (Calendar > Settings > Manage Accounts > Add account) to your Windows 10 Calendar app. Note that your subscribed calendars will *not* appear under the default Microsoft account calendar.

Then, in Calendar, press the Ellipsis at the top right and press Sync.